# is there an easier algorithm to solve this form problem?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display form when a button is clicked. But I want that the form only gets displayed when that specific button is clicked, but the form should be the same for all the buttons. I've thought of doing it setting a state for each button but like this it would be very repetitive I think. Is there an easier algorithm which can accomplish the job?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import DietForm from './dietform.js'

function AddDiet() {

    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false)
    const [display1, setDisplay1] = useState(false)

    const displayForm = () => {
        if (display === true) {
            setDisplay(false)
        }  else {
            setDisplay(true)
        }
    }

    const displayForm1 = () => {
        if (display1 === true) {
            setDisplay1(false)
        }  else {
            setDisplay1(true)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={displayForm} class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Lunes</button>
            {display ? <DietForm />  : "void 0"}
            <button onClick={displayForm1} class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Martes</button>
            {display1 ?  <DietForm /> : "void 0"}
            <button onClick={displayForm} class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Miercoles</button>
            <button onClick={displayForm} class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Jueves</button>
            <button onClick={displayForm} class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Viernes</button>
            <button onClick={displayForm} class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Sábado</button>
            <button onClick={displayForm} class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Domingo</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddDiet
```

Comment: So, you want to replace your specific `<button>` that is clicked with the `DietForm`, is that right?

Comment: no, i want the form to display under the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only difference in your `button` elements are the names, I would extract them to an array:

```
const BUTTONS = [Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves ...]
```

Then, I would keep a state variable for each button clicked:

```
const [clickedButtons, setClickedButtons] = useState([])
```

It's handler to toggle the button clicked/unclicked: (not sure if this is your use case)

```
const handleButtonClick = name => {
  setClickedButtons(buttons => (
    buttons.includes(name) ? buttons.filter(btn => btn !== name) : [...buttons, name]
  ))

}
```

And render them like:

```
{BUTTONS.map((btn, index) => (
 <>
  <button onClick={() => handleButtonClick(btn)}
    class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"> 
    {btn} 
  </button>
  {clickedButtons.includes(btn) && <DietForm />}
 </>
)}
```

#### Bonus

Here is a [codesandbox simulating your use case](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-gates-6zr3e?file=/src/App.js). You can see the live example and check the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wrapper component to reuse your logic, for example

```
const FormDisplayer = ({ children, btnTxt }) => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false)

  const displayForm = () => {
    if (display === true) {
        setDisplay(false)
    }  else {
        setDisplay(true)
    }
  }

  return (
     <>
      <button onClick={displayForm} class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">{btnTxt}</button>
      {display ? children : null}
    </>
  )
}

function AddDiet() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FormDisplayer btnTxt="Test">
        <DietForm />
      </FormDisplayer>
      <FormDisplayer btnTxt="Test2">
        <DietForm />
      </FormDisplayer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can edit the wrapper to better suit your needs and make it as reusable as possible

If the form is the same for each button, just remove children and replace with the DietForm component directly

Take a look
https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-dream-wm0f4?file=/src/App.js